# How to get String from TextField in Java

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, jpasswordfield

I am getting object from `TextField` and `PasswordField`, but I need to use it as a `String` in my class. I have variables set like this, but the application is crashing

```
@FXML private TextField email;
@FXML private PasswordField password;

private String stringPassword = password.getText();
private String stringEmail = email.getText();
```

Edit: I put the getText to the relevant method, with no success. Now I have

```
@FXML public void logIn() throws IOException    
{ 
    String p = password.getText();
    String e = email.getText();
    System.out.println(p);}
```

All this leading to NullPointerException

Comment: "The application is crashing". **What is the error ?**

Comment: You're trying to get the text from the text field when the controller is first created. The text field won't be initialized then - and the user certainly won't have had a chance to type anything in the text field. You typically get the text from a text field at the time you need it (e.g. in an event handler for something). What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 3):

you must not call this  `password.getText();` and `email.getText();` in that place.
because `TextField`and `PasswordField`are not initialized yet.
So you should call them in a method in your class.

Comment: Thank you, is was trying to do this, now I have tried following solution, with no results:String h = password.getText();
  String e = email.getText();
  System.out.println(h); -> NullPointerException

Comment: @JanMandík Where did you put that code? When is it being executed? If you have updated your code following this answer and it's still throwing exceptions, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50553743/edit) to show the new code (and the complete stack trace).